# Anylogic: how to link a wait block to a schedule of different agents

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, wait, anylogic

I've got a boat with capacity 1750 pp, that leaves the port every 2 hours based on a schedule.
The passengers arrives at a waiting area, they can leave this area if:

- there is a boat at the dock
- (the number of passengers already embarked + passengers that left the waiting area) < 1750

All these conditions are working properly, but since it takes time to get to the dock and due to safety protocols, I want to stop the passengers flow 2 minutes before the departure of the boat, in order to not have passengers not embarked on the dock.

How can I link the boat schedule (named schDepartureBoat1) with passengers Wait block (named waitForBoat1)?
At the moment I have the following code in the On enter action of the Wait block:

```
if(cllBoatDock1.size()>0 && (cllPedOnDock1.size()+cllPedOnBoat1.size()) < 1750) {
 waitForBoat1.freeAll();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most natural in this case would probably be a "Hold" block downstream of the "Wait" block.

2 minutes before departure, you call `myHoldBlock.block()`. No more agents leave the "Wait" block and they will have to stay until the next departure.

Just ensure to call `myHoldBlock.unblock()` when the next ship wants boarding to start.

Comment: How can I identify "2 minutes before departure"? 
Should I use another schedule related to passengers release or there's a simpler way to tell it to the wait block?

Comment: You can create a Dynamic Event when the schedule's 2-hr window starts (i.e. in the Schedule's "Action" code block) and call it in 118 mins: `create_MyDynamicEvent(118, MINUTE)`. In the DE, you block the hold block. Check the help and example models to learn about DEs